# Unable to Invoke Post Operation When Using a DTO for Grails

Tags: grails, dto

I would like to use a DTOs when I'm working with grails. My DTO basically looks like this:

```
class ProjectDTO {
   Long id
   Long version
   String name
}
```

I've put the file in src/groovy so grails understands this isn't a domain model. 
I also have a converter to transfrom my projectDTO into a project object.

```
@Transactional
def save(ProjectDTO projectInstance) {
if (projectInstance == null) {
    render status: NOT_FOUND
    return
}       
ProjectDTOConverter converter = new ProjectDTOConverter()
Project p =  converter.convertFromDTOForSave(projectInstance)
p = projectService.save(p)

List<ProjectDTO> r = converter.convertToDTO(p)
respond r, [status: CREATED]
}
```

This strategy seems to work fine for GET, POST, and DELETE operations, but not for PUT operations. It seems that for put operations, grails always considers my projectInstance variable to be null, even though it is passed in properly.

I did a SQL spool and it seems that when you pass in any object into a PUT operation, grails assumes you're working with a domain object, and issues a SQL statement to try retrieve the object from the database. If the object can't be retrieved, the projectInstance is nulled out for some reason.

Does anyone know if there is a way to instruct Grails that the object i'm passing in for a PUT operation is not a domain model, and grails shouldn't retrieve it from the database?

Comment: are you talking about the standard `update(ProjectDTO projectInstance)` method here? Grails is pulling the instance from the db if an id is given and binding the given attribute values to the instance. If, for any reason, you don't want this automatic binding, you can just declare `update()` without parameters and bind the incoming attributes by yourself (e.g. with `bindData`).  Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why do not use Command Objects for this purpose?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It's my understanding that data binding is used to map http request parameters to domain objects. But in my situation, I want to pass my project object in via the body of the request, just as I do for a post operation. My project object is a complex object so I would prefer not to pass in each field via an http request parameter.

Comment: It's my understanding that grails considers ProjectDTO a command object. It's located in src/groovy. I also see this warning when launching the application. Warning The [update] action accepts a parameter of type ProjectDTO which has not been marked with @Validateable. Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validatable. The problem is that on a PUT operation, grails seems to want to fetch the object by the id I've passed in.

Comment: true, DTO is just the same as a command object from grails point of view (perhaps it's just missing the `@Validateable` annotation as you already mentioned). I just asked because of the converter stuff you implemented by yourself. But if `converter.convertFromDTOForSave(projectInstance)` contains more logic than just copying the attributes, then it seems to make sense. As i already said, remove the method parameter and create an instance on your own. Im not really sure, what you mean by "pass in each field via an http request parameter".

Comment: So here's their documentation on using bindData: https://spring.io/blog/2012/03/28/secure-data-binding-with-grails
"A really common task for many web applications is for the application to accept a set of http request parameters and bind those parameters to an object." If I remove the method parameter and create the instance on my own, I have to do it by using http request parameters. The http request parameters are used to populate the params object that they mention in the documentation. I will have around 50 fields on this object, it would be difficult to pass them in as request parameters.

Comment: to use `bindData` it is not neccessary to pass the attributes that should be included / excluded as described in the [official docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) (although it makes sense from a security point of view). Just use `bindData(projectInstance, params)`.

Comment: The first parameter of dataBind is the target object. My target object is a Project, and my source object is a ProjectDTO. The second parameter in dataBind is a map of source parameters. I don't want to use the map object created via the simple list of http request parameters. I want to pass the contents of my post through the body of the request. If you pass in an id to the body of a command object via a POST, the whole command object is nulled out.